# Passing variable from javascript to php on the same file. Says successful, but undefined index when try to use it

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to have an on-click event that posts a variable through with ajax post. After the button is clicked, i get my succesful alert of the class name, but at the end, when I try to retreive the data via the post in my php, it is still left empty it seems. Anything i am missing here?(I used a for-loop to make the buttons).

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function sendClassNametoPhp()
                    {

                        var className = this.id;
                        console.log(className);

                        //figure out how to use ajax to post it to php
                            $.ajax({
                                    method: 'post',
                                    url: 'profilePage.php',
                                    data: {reqedClassName: JSON.stringify(className)},
                                    success: function() {alert(className);}

                            });

                    }
                    var numClasses = <?php echo $numClasses; ?>; 
                    //turn php $classnames into javasciprt classNames
                    var classNamesAvailable = <?php echo json_encode($classNames); ?>;

                    //loop to create a new href for each class (row in classes table)
                    for(var i=0; i < numClasses; i++)
                    {

                        //use json to get element
                         var jsonObject = classNamesAvailable[i];
                         var iterationClassName = jsonObject.ClassName;
                        //create registration button
                         var registerButton = document.createElement("button");
                         registerButton.id = iterationClassName;
                         registerButton.addEventListener("click", sendClassNametoPhp);

                         registerButton.innerHTML = iterationClassName;
                         var section = document.getElementById("availableClasses");
                         section.appendChild(registerButton);
                    }
            </script>
<?php 

    if(!empty($_POST['reqedClassName']))
     {
         $reqedClassName = $_POST['reqedClassName'];
         echo $reqedClassName;
     }

?>
```

Comment: It probably takes a while to get this information from the server side. Try to pass all the code to php and try again, for example:

Comment: <?php echo ("<script> function sendClassNametoPhp() { ...} </script>") ?>

Comment: Change `success: function()` to `success: function(data)`. Then `data` will contain the response from your PHP script. Javascript needs a place to store the response. You can't magically call it from nothing.

Comment: changed to success: function(data), still the same problem

Comment: Did you also change `alert(className);` to `alert(data);`? Also, please use @username when responding to someone. Otherwise they don't get an alert that you responded and have moved on to other questions :)

Comment: @icecub thank you! I changed it to alert(data). now it alerts the text content of the whole file, but i still dont get the intended php echo at the bottom. Do you know what that might mean?

Comment: @icecub maybe for some reason my data: paramater is not working, since it seems to think data is the whole file?

Comment: No it's because you have your PHP in the same file. Ajax simply gets _anything_ returned by the file. When you run that file, it'll return all output (html, css, js). You have to put the PHP code at the top of the file and make sure it doesn't return more than your echo. The most basic solution would be to put `exit();` right underneath the echo.

Comment: @icecub i tried moving that php segment to the top of the file and it still wont give me the echo after i push the button. I also tried making a new php file with it, same problem.

Comment: @icecube, however, it's not alerting the whole file anymore, just the correct variable value, which is good. But still php seems unable to get the Post.

Comment: @icecub anymore ideas for this?

Comment: If you don't update your code in your question to what you have now, it'll be hard for me to follow along. For the moment I think your biggest issue is `JSON.stringify(className)`. If className is just a string, "test" for example, that would result in `""test""`. Multiple quotes. You probably should just do `data: {reqedClassName: className }` instead.